# Existence of Ramsey type cardinal

Tags: combinatorics, logic, set-theory

Does the following assertion follows from ZFC.
For any cardinal $\beta$, is there a sufficiently large cartinal $\lambda$ such that for any coloring $f_n:[\lambda]^n\rightarrow \beta$ for each $n\in\omega$, there exists infinite set $X\subseteq \lambda$ such that $|f_n[X]^n|=1$ for all $n$.

This is weaker than existence of almost Ramsey cardinal.

Comment: These are Erdős cardinals.  Their existence is not provable in ZFC.  (In fact, for $\lambda\ge\omega_1,$ the partition property implies that $0^\sharp$ exists.)  http://cantorsattic.info/Erdos

Comment: To forestall any questions: I should have said that their existence is not provable in ZFC if ZFC is consistent.